# How to update and change existing customer address data using CSV

Tags: magento2, customer-data

- How to update and change existing customer address data using CSV.
- Also I have tried importing customer data using CSV but it creates a new address and not an existing address.
- system->import->customer addresses->Add/Update Complex Data.
- Then I import the data and check in the admin panel for the customer for whom address has updated.
- **But there the new row gets added and i want updated from the exist address only.**

Answer (score 0):

> **First, export customers and you get csv with all customer information. Now you can update customer data in CSV.
> After go into System > Data Transfer > Import and select customer entity. Select the Add/Update Complex Data in Import Behavior and start Import.**

[For More](https://meetanshi.com/blog/import-and-export-customers-in-magento-2/)

Comment: Yes I did it this way but it will update and add new rows.
I just want to update the data and not create a new address row in admin panle

Comment: So this is possible to update address without existing new address row?

Comment: You can update in csv and import it.